# Check if a CGPoint is inside a given view?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, frame

As the question itself is self explanatory, How do i check if a given point is inside a given frame of view.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve it through many ways

1. `UIView` `pointInside` method. It returns a Boolean value indicating whether the receiver contains the specified point.

   `-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`
2. `CGGeometry` `CGRectContainsPoint`method. It returns whether a rectangle contains a specified point.

   `bool CGRectContainsPoint (CGRect rect, CGPoint point);`
3. `CGGeometry` `CGPointEqualToPoint`method.It returns whether two points are equal.

   `bool CGPointEqualToPoint (CGPoint point1, CGPoint point2);`

Answer (score 9):

```
CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point);
```

Reference: [`CGRectContainsPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456316-cgrectcontainspoint?language=objc)

Comment: how to with swiftui?